# How to create custom 3D name using c# script in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, 3d, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I'm stuck on a c# scripting problem in Unity that I would like to solve.

This is what I want to achieve:

1. Enter a name on an InputField
2. Get Characters from the Input field
3. For each Character: set the 3D GameObject of the Character already created in the Hierarchy
4. SetCharacterPosition next to each other so they can create a name
5. SetMaterial in this order (Blue, Green,Red,Yellow) and start over
6. View the given input name in a 3D Colored way on the screen

This is what I have done so far:

1. Created 3D Prefabs of each Character and loaded into Hierarchy
2. Created the GUI with an InputField and a Button (+Script)
3. Create a Button Script (button_scr) in order to get the name and split into Characters

**GUI**
[image: The setup so far]
**SCRIPT button_scr**

```
public class button_scr : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Button myButton;
    public InputField un;
    public GameObject go;

    void Start () 
    {
        myButton = GetComponent<Button>();
        myButton.onClick.AddListener(ProcessText);
    }

    void ProcessText()
    {
        Debug.Log("Your name is : "+un.text);
        getCharacters(un.text);
    }

    void getCharacters(string text)
    {
        foreach (char c in text) 
        {
            go = GameObject.Find(""+char.ToUpper(c));
            go.SetActive (true);
            // setPosicionNext2EachOther
            // setColoredMaterial(Blue,Green,Red,Yellow) in this order 
            Debug.Log("GameObject name Log: "+go.name);     
        }
    }
}
```

Some considerations:

1. Names can have some repeated Characters
2. Names can have accent marks on vowels (Á, É,Í,Ó,Ú)
3. Names can have "ñ" character

This is where I would like to get some orientation in order to solve the problem:

- I have considered creating and filling a GameObject Array with all
  the references of each character like so:
- `GameObject[0] = A 3D Character prefab`
- `GameObject[1] = B 3D Character prefab`
- Then create a for loop to find the name character in the GameObject Array and make a copy in order to setup in the game
- Set 3D character position
- Set Material to 3D character in a sequential order (Blue,Green,Red,Yellow)

Is there any easier way to do this that I'm missing?

I would like to get some orientation/advice or some sample code where I can check similar issue solving.

Comment: I'm trying to decide if your question is too broad and/or should be migrated to [codereview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). I'm thinking the latter unless you have a specific problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

this is a quick solution. not tested. i dont have unity installed. just for you to have an idea.

Yes. is better to assign all the letters in a array for optimization. Also deactivate all the letters in Awake()

```
public Material materials[]; // assign the materials in the order you want

public void getCharacters (string name)
{
int materialIndex = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < text.lenght; i++)
{
    char c = char.ToUpper(text[i]);
    GameObject go = GameObject.Find("" + c);
    go.SetActive (true);

    go.transform.position = new Vector3(i, 0, 0); // place the letters in the x axis separated by one meter

    // change the material
    go.GetCOmponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial = materials[materialIndex];      
    materialIndex = (materialIndex + 1) % materials.length; // cycle the materials

    // setPosicionNext2EachOther
    // setColoredMaterial(Blue,Green,Red,Yellow) in this order 
    //Debug.Log("GameObject name Log: "+go.name);  
}
```

}